# volatile identifier in java

Tags: java, thread-safety, volatile

I dont understand those few statements that I read:

> because accessing a volatile variable never holds a lock, it is not
>   suitable for cases where we want to read-update-write as an atomic
>   operation (unless we're prepared to "miss an update");

What does it mean, I cant read-update-write?

When will I want to use volatile instead of  simple boolean. In C#, I remember that I could use a simple static bool to control when a thread starts and stops, but in java I need to use the identifier, "volatile":

```
> public class StoppableTask extends Thread {
  private volatile boolean pleaseStop;

  public void run() {
    while (!pleaseStop) {
      // do some stuff...
    }
  }

  public void tellMeToStop() {
    pleaseStop = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind missing the update and running an iteration or two "too much", then you don't need `volatile`. (You are not going to set it back to false again, right?) For "easier/safer/saner" tools to code concurrent code in Java, look at java.util.concurrent. It has thread management classes, and also an AtomicBoolean.

Comment: if you look at the algorithm , It should set it to true and false,, and prevent the loop from being infinite

Comment: @Thilo: No, you need `volatile`! Without it, it is not guaranteed that the Thread will ever see the flag set to `true`. Actually some compiler optimization could even remove the condition from the loop and make it an end-less loop.

Comment: @Thilo - If you don't use `volatile` in the above example you can make an infinite loop:)

Comment: I see. All the more reason to stop messing with the low-level stuff and use java.util.concurrent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The sentence speaks about this example:

```
public class CounterClass {
   private volatile int counter;

   public int increment() {
       return counter++;
   }
}
```

Although the `counter` has `volatile` modifier, it is not guaranteed that if two threads access the `increment()` method that two different integers will be returned. Because the `counter++` operation is not atomic. It is `get, increment, return`. It is possible that two threads call `increment()` at the same time and that the first thread is at the `get` phase and the second thread is at the `get` phase before the first thread is at the `increment` phase.

Summary: `volatile` doesn't guarantee atomicity or whatever. It just guarantees that when you access the variable, you will not receive an old cached value. But it doesn't guarantee any thread safety or atomicity.

Answer (score 2):

> When will I want to use volatile

FWIW Brian Goetz in [Managing volatility](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06197/) lists five patterns for using volatile:

1. status flags ("canonical")
2. one-time safe publication
3. independent observations ("an extension of the previous one")
4. the "volatile bean" pattern
5. the cheap read-write lock trick ("if reads greatly outnumber modifications")

---

BTW this image has helped me to figure memory guarantees for volatile:
  [image: https://farm4.static.flickr.com/3073/3035268779_f8a9dce89d.jpg]
  Above, `ready` is volatile. Note whatever guarantees are there, these are only for assignment, not for *read-update-write*

- Above image is taken from Jeremy Manson's blog article: [What Volatile Means in Java](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html).

  > "The first thread writes to `ready`, which is going to be the sender side of the communications. The second thread reads from ready  and sees the value the first thread wrote to it. It therefore becomes a receiver. Because this communication occurs, *all of the memory contents seen by Thread 1, before it wrote to ready, must be visible to Thread 2, after it reads the value true for ready.*"